# get all the textarea in page and replace their text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all the textarea in page and replace its text with selected textarea's text on button click.

```
$('.copyMsg').on('click', 'div',function(){
        var j=0;    
        var setText= $(this).parent().find('textarea').val();               
        $('.Cards textarea').each(function(i){
            $(this).text(setText);      
            console.log($(this).parent().attr('class'));
            j=i;
        });
        console.log(setText + ": "+j);
    });
```

problem occures when, if I chose second textarea then all the textarea below this get replaced not above it.

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/4y9wL/
I will be adding some textarea dynamically too

Comment: Seems to me, there is no class 'Cards' inside your HTML.

Comment: @anup: its a wrapper for all my contents,

Comment: Ok. Can you try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4y9wL/1/

Comment: @Anup. thanks but no, its not working

Comment: @Prasad: Just want to ensure you are clicking the right div ("copy message to all cards").

Comment: @Anup, please try following,
1. enter any no. eg. 1 in first textarea,click copy message to all cards,
2. enter no. 2 in second textarea, this will copy text to textarea3 and textarea4 but not to textarea1.
getting my point, Its leaving all previous textarea.

Answer (score 0):

please try with this code

```
$('.copyMsg').on('click',function(){        
    var setText= $(this).parent().find('textarea').val();   

    $('textarea').each(function(evt,val){
                   val.value = setText;                    
    });

});
```

and also find your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4y9wL/2/

Answer (score 0):

My fiddle solves your problem !

Here is the code :

```
$('.copyMsg').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click',function(){$('textarea').val($(this).prev().prev().val())});
});
```

[My Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y9wL/7/)

Mark it as answer if found helpful !

Comment: Good Try, thanks @amit, but it will not work for dynamically added .copyMsg or for textarea.
I was right, I just check your Fiddle its not working for dynamic functionality. Thanks Amit!

Comment: THANKS amit, you clicked me. I should have used .val() to set textarea text not .text().

Answer (score 0):

I have to use .val() to set textarea value not .text,

```
$('div').on('click','.copyMsg',function(){
        var j=i=-1;     
        var setText= $(this).parent().find('textarea').val();               
        $('textarea').each(function(i){
            //$(this).text(setText);
            $(this).val(setText);       
            console.log($(this).prev());    
            j=i;        
        });     
        console.log(j);
    });
```